# Problema Visual Studio For Mac

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Sou novo em Visual Studio For Mac.
Tenho um projeto que funciona normalmente no VS 2017.
Porém, quando tento "Buildar" ele apresenta o erro abaixo:

> Error MSB4100: Expected "!$(Disable_CopyWebApplication)" to evaluate
>   to a boolean instead of "!", in condition
>   "!$(Disable_CopyWebApplication) And '$(OutDir)' != '$(OutputPath)'".
>   (MSB4100)

Tenho que modificar alguma coisa para conseguir utilizar nas duas plataformas?